# Deleting a line in a file with C

Tags: c, file, line

I'm trying to delete a specific line in a file. I used the code at the bottom (copying the lines in another file and skipping the line I want to delete). But if I chose to delete any line other than the last one, the latter isn't shown in the the new file. Also, how can I delete a line while using a separator between the fields?!

```
int supprimerVoiture()
{
    FILE *fichierVoitures = NULL, *fileReceipient = NULL; // Pointeur sur fichier
    Voiture voiture;
    long idVoiture;

    fichierVoitures = fopen("fichiers/voitures.txt", "r");
    fileReceipient = fopen("fichier/voituresNew.txt", "w");

    if (fichierVoitures != NULL && fileReceipient != NULL)
    {
        printf("\n-Enter the ID of the car u want to delete : ");
        idVoiture = lireLong();

        while (fscanf(fichierVoitures, "%8ld %14s %14s %7s %2ld %5ld %4s", &voiture.idVoiture, voiture.marque, voiture.nomVoiture, voiture.couleur, &voiture.nombrePlaces, &voiture.prixJour, voiture.enLocation) == 7)
        {
            if (idVoiture != voiture.idVoiture)
            {
                fprintf(fileReceipient, "%8ld %14s %14s %7s %2ld %5ld %4s", voiture.idVoiture, voiture.marque, voiture.nomVoiture, voiture.couleur, voiture.nombrePlaces, voiture.prixJour, voiture.enLocation);

                fprintf(fileReceipient, "\n");
            }
        }

        fclose(fichierVoitures);
        fclose(fileReceipient);

        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nImpossible d'ouvrir le fichier");

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `voiture.marque` is too small.  Post a [mcve] and sample data.

Comment: use fgets instead when reading from the file, then sscanf

Comment: Your `fscanf()` won't work if any of the string fields have spaces in them, since they'll be treated as the field delimiter. `%s` only reads a single word.

Comment: _"how can I delete a line while using a separator between the fields?!"_ Can you explain this more in depth?